# Bootstrap carousel auto starting with data attributes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel, custom-data-attribute

I'm using Bootstrap Carousel. From the Bootstrap docs:

> You can use all Bootstrap plugins purely through the markup API
>   without writing a single line of JavaScript

My carousel html is exactly as per the docs, and begins with:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
```

I've then added the attributes `data-pause="hover"` and `data-interval="2000"`. My understanding is that the carousel should start cycling on page load (remember that you can use the plugins without a single line of JS), with an interval of 2000ms and pausing on hover.

But it doesn't - all other functions work, but to start the carousel cycling I must call:

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel();
```

And even then it cycles at the default interval of 5000ms (I'm aware I can change this by passing a settings object).

Is it right that I have to call the js manually to start the carousel and set the interval and pausing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you do have to initialize the carousel with JavaScript. It's a known issue:

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/7508

Comment: Thanks - your link points to a fix, but unfortunately it will be in v3 only.